# How to do react project from the cloud with cross platform workstations?

Tags: reactjs, cloud

I am rather new to several of the technologies involved here but here is the scenario:

I have a Windows PC at home, a PC laptop and an iPad Pro. I have a React project that I am working on and would like to be able to do so from anywhere. I dont have any kind of VPN solution available, and a usb stick is mostly out for the iPad, so I was wanting to use Google Drive (or as a last resort iCloud) to store the project. Also I do not wish to use github for a number of reasons.

Can anyone outline the best way to work on a React project (With NodeJS) in a cloud based storage and further how to run / deploy it from the iPad station? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I Think you have to use a git repository (github, gitlab or bitbucket works great), and all your machines should have the tools pre-installed (node, code editor).

If you want to code without any tool, I recommend https://codesandbox.io, it works great with small/medium projects. One of it's downside is that your projects will be public on the internet.

Comment: I will have a look at that link for sure, but it being pubic is also a downside to github (In addition to having a bit of a learning curve). I was afraid this might be the case, I really wanted to stay away from github (and any other public internet method). At the end of the day it may well be my only option.

Comment: Actually you can have free private repository on github, and deploy react apps using netlify. Codesandbox.io offers private projects but it's paid.

Comment: Oh that is a great point! I didn’t realize that it comes with a free private one. I suppose may only remaining issue with it is that I have to learn the git structure and software / commands etc. I am new to React and the files are all generated unlike old school projects. You seem really knowledgeable! Can I ask, what is the reason google drive wouldn’t work for this?

Comment: Git is a versioning tool, it's very different from a cloud storage like google. I really recommend you to use github, it's very intuitive and straight forward. Nowadays every company uses git, it's easy to maintain the code and work with teams.